# weblogic server state control script

Tags: python, weblogic

this is weblogic control script but script end fail with this error -- |Temporary| Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last): File "/appdata/weblogic/scripts/checkInstanceByWlst.py", line 63, in sValueError: invalid literal for **int**: Temporary -- but there is no problem in the code
can you help me?

```
`def serverStatus(server):
 try:
 cd('/ServerLifeCycleRuntimes/' + server.getName())
 return cmo.getState()
 except ConnectionException,e:
 return "NOT_REACHABLE"

adminName = sys.argv[1]
URL= "t3://" + sys.argv[2]
date = sys.argv[3]
unixDate = sys.argv[4]

temp_list = []

username = str(sys.argv[5])
password = str(sys.argv[6])

try:
connect(username,password,URL) 
except ConnectionException,e:
print '\033[1;31m Unable to find admin server...\033[0m'
exit()

#domainRuntime()

#servers=cmo.getServerLifeCycleRuntimes()
webVer = version
webVer = webVer.split(' ')[2].split('.')[0]

servers = cmo.getServers()
domainRuntime()

print '|' + webVer + '|'

for server in servers:
    openSocketCount = "0"
    idleTC = "0"
    executeTC = "0"
    hoggerTC = "0"
    stuckTC = "0"
    serverName = str(server.getName())
    if serverName != adminName:
       f2 = open( '.servers.donotdelete', 'a' )
       f2.writelines( str(server.getName()) + "\n" )
       f2.close()

       serverState = serverStatus(server)

       if serverState != "RUNNING":
          serverHealth = "NOT_REACHABLE" 
       else:
          #cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + serverName)
         # serverHealth = str(cmo.getHealthState())
          try:
             cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + str(server.getName()))
             serverHealth = str(cmo.getOverallHealthState())
             serverHealth = serverHealth.split('State:')[1].split(',')[0]
             openSocketCount = str(get('OpenSocketsCurrentCount'))
             cd('ThreadPoolRuntime/ThreadPoolRuntime/')
             idleTC = str(get('ExecuteThreadIdleCount'))
             executeTC = str(get('ExecuteThreadTotalCount') - get('StandbyThreadCount'))
             hoggerTC = str(get('HoggingThreadCount'))
             if int(webVer) > 11:
                stuckTC = str(get('StuckThreadCount'))

             cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + str(server.getName()))
             dataSources = cmo.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
             if (len(dataSources) > 0):
                for dataSource in dataSources:
                   if  str(dataSource.getState()) != "Running":
                      f1 = open( '.datasources.donotdelete', 'a' )
                      f1.writelines( str(server.getName()) + ' | ' + str(dataSource.getName()) + ' | 
    ' + str(dataSource.getState()) + "\n" )
                      f1.close()

          except Exception,e:
             serverHealth = "NOT_REACHABLE"
             #continue

          #serverHealth = str(cmo.getOverallHealthState())
          #serverHealth = serverHealth.split('State:')[1].split(',')[0]
          #openSocketCount = str(get('OpenSocketsCurrentCount'))
          #cd('ThreadPoolRuntime/ThreadPoolRuntime/')
          #idleTC = str(get('ExecuteThreadIdleCount'))
          #executeTC = str(get('ExecuteThreadTotalCount') - get('StandbyThreadCount'))
          #hoggerTC = str(get('HoggingThreadCount'))
          #if int(webVer) > 11:
          #   stuckTC = str(get('StuckThreadCount'))

          #cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + server.getName())
          #dataSources = cmo.getJDBCServiceRuntime().getJDBCDataSourceRuntimeMBeans()
          #if (len(dataSources) > 0):
          #   for dataSource in dataSources:
          #      if  str(dataSource.getState()) != "Running":
          #          f1 = open( '.datasources.donotdelete', 'a' )
          #          f1.writelines( str(server.getName()) + ' | ' + str(dataSource.getName()) + ' | ' 
       + str(dataSource.getState()) + "\n" )
          #          f1.close()
       f = open( '.' + str(server.getName()) + '.donotdelete', 'a' )
       f.writelines( date + '|' + unixDate + '|' + serverState + '|' + serverHealth + '|' + 
       openSocketCount + '|' + idleTC + '|' + executeTC + '|' + hoggerTC + '|' + stuckTC + "\n")
       f.close()`
```

**This works successfully on Weblogic version 12.2.1.1.0 but not on 10.3.3.**

Comment: You need to fix your indentation. Re-paste your code, select your code and then enter ctrl-k.

Comment: this my full python code ;) 
I run this as follows.
${WLST_PATH}/wlst.sh checkInstanceByWlst.py ${ADMIN_SERVER_NAME} ${ADMIN_SERVER_URL} ${DATE} ${unixDATE} ${ADMIN_USER} ${ADMIN_PASS

Comment: You did not understand my comment at all. If I were to copy and paste the source you posted, it would not compile at all because the indentation is all wrong. LOOK AT IT. I attempted to tell you how you should have entered it correctly. It's not too late. You can edit your post and re-copy and re-paste your source as I have indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i resolved as below.

Python file;
`connect('user','pass','t3://**.**.**.**:7001') x=ls('Servers',returnMap='true') for i in x: state(i,'Server')`